# Inconsistent BigQuery datatypes returned client side via Dataflow Java API

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Given the BigQuery table:

[image]

And the following client side code:

```
private void testTypes(Iterable<TableRow> table) {
        for(TableRow tr: table){
            Object x = tr.get("an_integer");
            Object y = tr.get("a_float");
            Object z = tr.get("a_string");
            System.out.println(x.getClass().getTypeName());
            System.out.println(y.getClass().getTypeName());
            System.out.println(z.getClass().getTypeName());
        }
}
```

It produces:

```
java.lang.String
java.lang.Double
java.lang.String
```

Why is a String returned for an INTEGER?

<s>Why is a Double returned for a FLOAT?</s>

Comment: I can answer DOUBLE for FLOAT thing - it is just a terminology. In BigQuery, FLOAT means 64 bit floating number (same in many other commercial databases), and in Java, Double means 64 bit floating number.

Comment: I can answer STRING for INTEGER thing. Some languages (Javascript) represents all numbers as floating point, which means that not all 64 bit integers can be represented. To avoid this accidental rounding, INTEGERs are always quoted when on the wire. This results in them appearing as String in Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you got two comments explaining the behavior. I will copy them here to put a real answer to your question

From [Mosha Pasumansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4490873/mosha-pasumansky) :

"I can answer DOUBLE for FLOAT thing - it is just a terminology. In BigQuery, FLOAT means 64 bit floating number (same in many other commercial databases), and in Java, Double means 64 bit floating number."

From [Michael Sheldon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1371484/michael-sheldon) :
" I can answer STRING for INTEGER thing. Some languages (Javascript) represents all numbers as floating point, which means that not all 64 bit integers can be represented. To avoid this accidental rounding, INTEGERs are always quoted when on the wire. This results in them appearing as String in Java"